# My self.present for present storyboard is not working

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a mini sandbox, where I put a new Storyboard with a simple viewController with the label tutorial, all is just connected, I want to show the storyboard if the user defaults indicates that is the first time to see the tutorial. My TutorialModule.storyboard has a tutViewController and is the initialViewcontroller here is my code

```
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    let showTutorial = preferences.bool(forKey: "showTutorial")

    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard()
    var controller = UIViewController()

    if( !showTutorial ) {

        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "TutorialModule", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()! as UIViewController

        self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: all this code is in the viewDidLoad() in the main storyboard

Comment: Is the control coming inside the if condition

Comment: I dont understand what do u mean ? the control can be inside the if condition, the problem is isnt showing the storyboard TutorialModule even if I remove the if condition

Comment: whell like Im say, the problem is not the condition, I can remove the condition and still not working, thx in advanced for take to look

Comment: You can't present another controller in `viewDidLoad`, it needs to be somewhere like `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I even put a button with an action to call the storyboard, and its working fine but I cant make this happend on the didViewLoad

Comment: ok, @dan that works for me, I put the code in viewDidAppear, put your answer so I can give u my vote, thx